# multiple sequential definitions, defining own set function

Tags: programming

I want to define a function for doing multiple definitions, where I apply the same function `f` to all values, and definitions are done not at the same time but after each other.

A simple example: the function I want is `multiDef`, where

```
multiDef[{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, a}}, f]
```

should be identical to the sequence of assignments

```
a = f[1];
b = f[2];
c = f[a];
```

A simple attempt, with slightly different syntax, is

```
multiDef[list1_List, list2_List, fct_] /; Length[list1] == Length[list2] := 
  list1 = fct /@ list2
```

Aside from the different syntax the problem here is that it will not set `c` to `f[f[1]]`, but to `f[a]` (or to `f[5]` if we had `a = 5` before running this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first proposed syntax of `multiDef` can be implemented like this:

```
SetAttributes[multiDef, HoldAll]
multiDef[{b:{_Symbol, _}...}, f_] :=
  (CompoundExpression @@ Replace[Hold[b], {s_, v_} :> (s = f@v), {1}];)
```

The key is make sure that the symbols in the argument list are not evaluated until after the appropriate `Set` expressions have been assembled.  This is necessary to prevent the symbols from being replaced by any existing values that they may already have.

The `HoldAll` attribute prevents such unwelcome evaluation of the argument list.  Inside the function, we temporarily wrap the symbol/value pairs in `Hold` to prevent further evaluation of the pairs as we operate upon them.  `Replace` is used to transform each pair into an assignment.  Finally, we convert the `Hold` expression into a `CompoundExpression`, adding an extra semicolon after the last assignment.

Here is `multiDef` in action:

```
multiDef[{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3 + 4}}, f]

{a, b, c}
(* {f[1], f[2], f[7]} *)
```

Note that the definition ensures that the supplied variable values are not evaluated prior to passing them to the supplied function -- in case that function wants to hold them itself:

```
multiDef[{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3 + 4}}, Hold]

{a, b, c}
(* {Hold[1], Hold[2], Hold[3 + 4]} *)
```

We can use `TracePrint` to peek under the covers and see the result of the `Replace` transformation:

```
TracePrint[multiDef[{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3 + 4}}, f], _CompoundExpression]
(*
   CompoundExpression @@ Replace[Hold[{a,1},{b,2},{c,3+4}],{s$_,v$_}:>(s$=f[v$]),{1}];
   a = f[1]; b = f[2]; c = f[3+4]
*)
```

When defining macros like `multiDef`, it is a good idea to signal an error if the expression does not conform to the expected syntax:

```
m:multiDef[___] := (Message[multiDef::malformed, HoldForm[m]]; Abort[])
multiDef::malformed = "Malformed arguments in ``";
```

This extra definition will catch simple syntax errors as they happen rather than blindly carrying on with the evaluation:

```
multiDef[{a, b, c}, f]
(*
   multiDef::malformed: Malformed arguments in multiDef[{a,b,c},f]
   $Aborted
*)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. The compound expression guarantees evaluation in the order of input.

Answer (score 3):

If `a`, `b` and `c` do not already have values, you can simply use

```
In[1]:= (#1 = f[#2]) & @@@ {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, a}}
Out[1]= {f[1], f[2], f[f[1]]}

In[2]:= a
Out[2]= f[1]

In[3]:= b
Out[3]= f[2]

In[4]:= c
Out[4]= f[f[1]]
```

If they do have values then I do not recommend storing the input in a simple list such as `{{a,1}, ...}`.  It is necessary to [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hold.html) the result in some way, e.g. `Hold[{a,1}, ...]`.  Then you can use the same solution from above and use [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReleaseHold.html)at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this construct if your left- and right-hand sides are in different lists:

```
MapThread[Set, {{a, b, c}, f /@ {1, 2, a}}]
{a, b, c}
```

> {f[1], f[2], f[f[1]]}

@Szabolcs's remarks are equally applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
m = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, a}};
(Evaluate@m[[;; , 1]]) = f /@ m[[;; , 2]]

(*{f[1], f[2], f[f[1]]}*)
```

One thing I want to add, when you run this, a,b, and c will not be empty symbols. So I would suggest you add clear command if you want to always run this.

```
Clear[a, b, c]
```